# configure jetty ssl in heroku

Tags: grails, ssl, heroku, jetty

I have a standalone launcher for jetty inside server directory. I have some jeytty configuration  code there. I need to configure jetty to work with http and https connectors.
As I understand heroku supplies custom port to launch jetty on. It's not clear what port can i use to configure SSL connector. Also it's unclear should I provide any certificate for jetty if I use piggyback addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to configure Jetty for SSL at all. Heroku will terminate the SSL endpoint at the routing layer and handle it for you from there. The config options in Jetty are for when Jetty is expecting to act as the SSL endpoint.