# Node.js + SSL on Heroku. SSL handled by Nginx or Node.js?

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, nginx, express

I'm currently using

`Express 2.x`

`Node 0.8.x`

---

Do I have to pass

`key` and `cert` parameters to express.createServer() to handle SSL by Node.js?

Or SSL is handled by Nginx on Heroku?

Comment: Answered succinctly here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23894573/1882064

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, SSL termination happens at the load balancer, before encrypted traffic reaches your node app:

```
browser <--HTTPS--> nginx <--HTTP--> node
```

You can check `req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https'` to see which protocol the request came in with.

Related: [configure jetty ssl in heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869459/configure-jetty-ssl-in-heroku)

Comment: So at least I don't have to handle SSL on node.js but just in Heroku command client :) Right?